# How do I set a parameter in a Rails OAuth request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, omniauth

I have a Rails app that uses the `omniauth-github` gem. According to [Github documentation](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/#web-application-flow), I can set the parameter `allow_signup` to false in the initial request, so that users can only log in to my app if they already have a Github account. This is my desired behavior.

The part I haven't been able to figure out is this: where exactly should I set this parameter? I have added it to the sign in link path (`"auth/github?allow_signup=false"`), but that doesn't work. Should this be in the `provider :github` line within `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`? How, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work:

```
# config/initializers/omniauth.rb

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :github,
    ENV['GITHUB_KEY'],
    ENV['GITHUB_SECRET'],
    {
      client_options: {
        authorize_url: 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?allow_signup=false'
      }
    }
end
```

Apparently it also works with Devise, replacing `provider` with `config.omniauth` and placing this within `config/initializers/devise.rb` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the parameter explicitly to `provider` function. So please try the following snippet.

```rb
provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_KEY'], ENV['GITHUB_SECRET'], allow_signup: 'true', scope: 'user,repo,gist'
```

Comment: Thank you, but that does not seem to work. I got it to work and I'm posting how as a separate answer.